# Define an extra field for all pages (with no plugin?)

Tags: functions, custom-field, pages

I usually use WP Types define custom fields, post types, ...

But I have a theme a little bit overloaded of plugins, so I would like to define this field for (all) the pages in functions.php if posible,

Lets say a field with id 'title-short'

Do you know howto?

Comment: What is title-short

Comment: Its just an additional field, could be named whatever else..

Comment: Many of the "metabox" questions will tell you how to do this (if I understand you and I am  not sure I do). Have you searched?

Comment: Maybe you want something as simple as this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92566/21376

Comment: Or this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137597/21376

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was looking for `add_post_meta` function, thank you all!